# Почему приложение при запуске увеличенное?

Tags: android, java

Хочу узнать, почему это приложение при запуске такое увеличенное, хотя в коде ничего нету...  https://github.com/robhinds/AndroidRssReader

[image]

Comment: А что значит увеличенное?..

Comment: Физический размер через скриншоты не передается. Кроме того, вы можете задать этот вопрос самому автору, а не тут.

Comment: Я к тому, что тема Holo.Dialog реально очень большая по себе. Такое чувство, что увеличенное. Фактически эта тема очень мелко выглядит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни в коде, ни в ресурсах нет ничего, что задавало бы какой-либо конкретный размер, зависящий от размеров экрана. Что по поводу темы Holo.Dialog, не знаю, где [[@sviter-pro](/users/19733/sviter-pro)](/users/19733/sviter-pro) нашел её в коде - в манифесте не указана какая-то конкретная тема.

Из всего этого делается вывод, что конфигурация используемой темы и UI-элементов на вашем устройстве использует по умолчанию "увеличенное" значение размеров шрифта, например. Т.е на других устройствах, вполне вероятно, все будет не таким уж и "увеличенным", как у вас. Думаю, это то, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: И я про тоже самое имею ввиду.... В коде ничего про нее нету, а она есть! Мистика....

Comment: Это не "мистика", а всего лишь "особая" конфигурация темы приложения на вашем устройстве( догадываюсь, на планшете ).